# Race condition on website deployment

Tags: web, deployment, race-condition

Say I have a website with 2 files, which are statically hosted on S3:

1. `index.html`
2. `script.js`

I have a scheme where these files are updated via a `git pull` from a remote origin every time I push. This got me thinking, though, that there's the possibility for a request to be made to the server as a `git pull` is happening to update the files. This seems like it could create two problems that would cause page errors:

1. A partially-updated `index.html` or `script.js` is returned.
2. An old `index.html` is returned to the client. The files are then updated on the server. The client then makes a request for `script.js`, which returns the new version.

What is a good practice for mitigating these two issues?

I imagine the first issue won't be a problem, assuming filesystem operations are atomic and the files are updated in a single go. However, I haven't seen anything that addresses the second issue, which seems more difficult to address.

Answer (score 0):

One way of addressing #2 is to use the cache-busting method of programmatically adding a hash to the script.js filename on compile, e.g.
`<script src="script.js">` becomes `<script src="script-79b1264ad3bc303fd.js">`

Now, when `script-[whatever].js` is requested via a non-matching `index.html`, the client gets a 404 rather than the wrong script.

As for how you'd go about deploying this, it depends on your build pipeline. Are you using Grunt/Gulp/etc?